# Javascript Get all number from array

Tags: javascript

From Array get only number into a new array or a string

```js
var fetchMIDarray = [
  'Corp: nameofthecompany (345961663886)',
  'Chain: somerandomname (372395416889)'
]
```

except result for new array should be:

```js
var fetchnumber =['345961663886','372395416889']
```

I know how this works for the string but unable to do same for array
code sinppet for string.

```js
var midname='Corp: Best Buy ApplePay/Partsearch (345961663886)';
var matches2 = midname.match(/\d+/);
console.log(matches2);
```

Comment: So... do that in a loop?

Comment: `fetchMIDarray.flatMap(string => string.match(/\d+/))` returns what you seek. Note that `/\d+/` only finds the first number in a string. If there can be multiple numbers in a string use `/\d+/g` (`g` - global flag) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let arr = ['Corp: nameofthecompany (345961663886)', 'Chain: somerandomname (372395416889)'];
let res = arr.map(x => x.match(/\d+/)[0]);
console.log(res);
```